ingress nginx error with no error in log file
i'm trying to deploy my app: front: angular and back:nestjs using docker and kubernetes ingress on my local windows machine. so locally my app is working, i push the app on docker hub locally and still working, i deploy it on kubernetes :
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: smartagri-back 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: smartagri-back
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: smartagri-back
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: smartagri-back
        image: maryem1994/smartagri:back-3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: smartagri-back
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: smartagri-back

and for frontend:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: smartagri-front 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: smartagri-front
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: smartagri-front
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: smartagri-front
        image: maryem1994/smartagri:front-3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: smartagri-front
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: smartagri-front

and finally my nginx yaml file:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: smartagri-app.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /saback
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: smartagri-back
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: smartagri-front
                port:
                  number: 80

but always it shows me 500 error.
PS: the ingress controller shows me nothing ! no errors.

Where is the port 3000 counterpart in the smartagri-back service?

So the solution is that i run this command:
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

and everything worked
